# GET request to multiple pages of URL and 400 bad request

Tags: python-3.x, get, python-requests, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I am to get the data from this url: http://requests.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/data/9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057 with a parameter page from 1 to 10 choosing the appropriate method from GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS. Tried this code to access the first page, but it didn't work:

```
import requests as rq
data_1 = rq.get('http://requests.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/data/9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057/?page=1', params={'page': '1'})
data_1
```

whatever I've tried - always getting 400 bad request in response.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing the GET parameters twice, which is likely resulting in a malformed URL. Try running

```
import requests as rq
data_1 = rq.get(
    'http://requests.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/data/9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057/', 
    params={'page': '1'},
)
```

Comment: now it gives me 404 error, and also says " '_xsrf' argument missing from POST"

Comment: @DianaPavlova That's an issue with the API you are using, not with the `requests` library. Are you sure the URL you are using is valid, and that the resource can be accessed via GET?

Comment: it must be valid, and about GET I'm not quite sure, but when i opened the website and with F12 opened the consol, it showed Request Method GET